# accesing data from HTML chart

Tags: html, browser, charts, browser-cache

I am using HTML stock chart, which uses library from https://www.chartiq.com.
It contains stock price data.

My query is, how do I save this data to disk.

I have tried to drill-down in browser's developer tools to see any data object reference.

But actually I do not really know what element or object to look for.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it (using Mozilla Firefox latest version).

Go to developer tools -- Network tab.

Refresh the chart.

One can see the "GET" requests executed.

One of those showing "cause" as XHR and with considerable data size, contains data fetched.

Now how to grab the data---

Right click on that entry, and select "Copy"--"Copy 
Response".

Then open a text editor and paste.

Yay, the data in JSON format is there  :)

Comment: One more point is left unclear. Where was this data stored? What was the location?